# Keras error "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input" while trying to train a model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I've been following a tutorial on training a model and I've stumbled across an error that I've been struggling to find a solution for.

The code for the model training is bellow:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

X = X / 255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             optimizer = 'adam',
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
```

And the result I get when I run this code is:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        28              metrics = ['accuracy'])
>        29 
>   ---> 30 model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
>
> ~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
>   **kwargs)
>       731         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       732         workers=workers,
>   --> 733         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       734 
>       735   def evaluate(self,
>
> ~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, **kwargs)
>       215           validation_data=validation_data,
>       216           validation_steps=validation_steps,
>   --> 217           distribution_strategy=strategy)
>       218 
>       219       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)
>
> ~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, sample_weights,
>   class_weights, steps_per_epoch, validation_split, validation_data,
>   validation_steps, shuffle, distribution_strategy)
>       468                      'at same time.')
>       469 
>   --> 470   adapter_cls = data_adapter.select_data_adapter(x, y)
>       471 
>       472   # Handle validation_split, we want to split the data and get the training
>
> ~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py
>   in select_data_adapter(x, y)
>       446         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
>       447         "input: {}, {}".format(
>   --> 448             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
>       449   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
>       450     raise RuntimeError(
>
> ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: , ( containing values of types {""})

Thank you in advance if you can help me figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Did you fix it? I too have run into the same error and am kind of struck.
Please let me know if you have found a solution.

Comment: Yes, basically you need to convert X and y as arrays before you load from pickle. All you have to do is at the top **import numpy as np** and then just change where you define X and y to: 
**X = np.asarray(pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb")))** and then:
**y = np.asarray(pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb")))** @tvbharath

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your data. `{""}` means you have a Python dict that only contains an empty string.